# Why can't my Nikon D7500 control a Nikon SB-900 attached to the hot shoe via the 'Flash Control mode (external)' menu?

Tags: nikon, flash, metz, nikon-d7500

I have Nikon D7500. Unfortunately, my flash SB 900 is not fully compatible with this camera.
When the flash is attached to the camera the function "Flash Control mode (external)" will not work, and for example monitor pre-flashes cannot be turned off.
I was thinking of buying Metz 52 AF-1, but I am not sure if this flash will be better for my camera?
Maybe there are other flashes (except for Nikon SB 5000) these work better
with Nikon D 7500?

Comment: [Shopping questions are not allowed on stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed) as a whole. You may want to reword this question to avoid closure.

Comment: The menu "Flash Control Mode" is strictly and only for the internal flash (so no effect on the SB-900).  The SB-900 uses it's own menu, but this camera menu is all the internal flash has.  Any TTL requires preflashes, but Manual flash mode does not use them.

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaken. The SB-900 is fully compatible with the D7500.  Just because the flash doesn't do what you think it should do does not mean it's not compatible. Miscommunication between the camera and flash means that you could have the flash mis-seated in the hotshoe; the contacts/pins might be broken/dirty, the wires inside the flash might be broken; or the microswitch that tells the camera a flash is mounted on the hotshoe may be broken. IOW, it may be your copy of the speedlight or your camera hotshoe, not the model of flash that's the issue.

Pre-flashes can mostly be turned off if you don't use TTL. But TTL requires a metering pre-flash to work.  And Nikon's wireless command mode requires pre-flashes to communicate settings changes.  You can use an IR filter over the pop-up flash, or switch to radio triggering to turn that off, but any 3rd-party flash with CLS optical master capability would be exhibiting the same behavior.

Just me, but switching from a Nikon speedlight to a 3rd-party speedlight (even a Metz) and expecting *better* compatibility is not being particularly realistic. 3rd-party manufacturers typically reverse-engineer the electronic communication and as a result of that, are most often victim to future incompatibility (which is why so many 3rd-party flashes have firwmare upgrade features).

In addition to this, Metz Mecatech went out of business last year (2020). Just saying.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.


I received a message from Nikon. They claim that the SB900 flash 
does not work with the Nikon D7500 and there is no firmware update.

`As we could confirm, the SB-900 cannot be controlled by the camera body using the "flash control mode". Unfortunately, and although we always advise to have the latest firmware, this will not solve the issue. 
Your suggestion/request of having a firmware update that allows you to control the flash on the camera body has been registered, with hope that Nikon may launch that update.`

Comment: I'm very skeptical Nikon said that. They might have said most SB-flashes having their own menus (SB-600, SB-700, SB-800, SB-900, SB-910) were not compatible with the camera internal menu, which is not the way most flashes work anyway. And this Nikon publication says those are compatible with D7500 in the regular way flashes work.    https://onlinemanual.nikonimglib.com/d7500/en/pdf/cls-compatible_flash_units.pdf     Only the flashes without their own menus (SB-300, SB-400, SB-500) must use the camera menu.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice.

I will check again the latest software updates for the flash and camera.
However, I will not be able to do it until the end the June, because I do not have this flash with me.

I hope your advice will be helpful.

Below you can find the full email I received from Nikon Europe support.

```
Case #: 04476320
Subject: Nikon D7500 with SB-900 (Flash control function)
Dear Grzegorz,

Thank you for contacting Nikon Product Support.

We are sorry to hear about your issue between the D7500 and the SB-900.

As we could confirm, the SB-900 cannot be controlled by the camera body using the "flash control mode". Unfortunately, and although we always advise to have the latest firmware, this will not solve the issue. 
Your suggestion/request of having a firmware update that allows you to control the flash on the camera body has been registered, with hope that Nikon may launch that update.

Besides the camera's user manual, you can check the options regarding speedlights, on the advanced speedlight compatibility chart (below), under unified flash control line, after selecting the D7500.

https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000006312&lang=en_GB&setRedirect=true

Hope this information helps to clarify your query.

Should you need any further assistance, do not hesitate to contact us.

Kind regards,
```

I will post an update on this issue after upgrading software (if newer will be available).